# NOT NULL constraint failed: core_question.poll_id error

Tags: python-3.x, django, api, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm stack on problem with POST method in Django.
Core Idea of the project to make Polls, in polls add questions, and for each question to add Answers.

I did make all of that. And i have few APIs working:

GET: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/poll/`
Showing all created polls in database

GET: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/poll/{poll_name}/`
poll_name -> Weather (for example) Showing all questions, all answers and correct answer

POST: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/token/`
Providing authorization Token if admin credentials are correct. (username: Admin, password: admin)

But now I need APIs for add, remove, update Polls, Questions and Answers.

I did try it for Questions first:

```
class Questions(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None, **kwargs):
        question = Question.objects.filter(poll__title=kwargs['topic'])
        serializer = QuestionSerializer(question, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None, **kwargs):
        serializer = QuestionSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

But i'm getting error: NOT NULL constraint failed: core_question.poll_id error

I did try to search it in Internet and its says that i'm not requesting proper parameter's.
I did try 100 variations and still cant find what is the problem.

This is Github link for project: https://github.com/NeoVic2006/Polls_with_questions_answers

Please check it and let me know where is the problem.
PLEASE be specific since i'm not really experienced in Django.

Thank you,

P.S:

My serializes:

```
    from rest_framework import serializers
    from .models import Answer, Polls, Question


class PollSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
       model = Polls
       fields = [
           'title', 
          
       ]


class AnswerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Answer
        fields = [
            'id',
            'answer_text',
            'is_right',
        ]


class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    answer = AnswerSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
       model = Question
       fields = [
           'title',
           'answer'
       ]
```

My Models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.deletion import DO_NOTHING


class Polls(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Poll'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Polls'
        ordering = ['id']

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    title  = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="New Poll", verbose_name="Poll Title")
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_over = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Question(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Question'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Questions'
        ordering = ['id']

    TYPE = (
        (0, 'Text'),
        (1, 'Single Choise'),
        (2, 'Multiple Choise')
    )

    poll = models.ForeignKey(Polls, related_name='question', on_delete=DO_NOTHING)
    title  = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="Title")
    technique = models.IntegerField(choices=TYPE, default=0, verbose_name="Type of question")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Answer(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Answer'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Answers'
        ordering = ['id']

    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, related_name='answer', on_delete=DO_NOTHING)
    answer_text = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="Answer text")
    is_right = models.BooleanField(default=False)
 
    def __str__(self):
        return self.answer_text
```

URLS in core:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include 
from rest_framework.authtoken.views import obtain_auth_token


urlpatterns = [
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/token/', obtain_auth_token, name='obtain-token'),
    path('poll/', include('core.urls', namespace='poll'))
]
```

URLS in app:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from .views import Poll, Questions

app_name ="Poll"

urlpatterns = [
    path('', Poll.as_view(), name="Poll"),
    path('<str:topic>/', Questions.as_view(), name="question"),
]
```

Comment: do you get this error when you try to `POST` to the shown view ? also share you serializers, your urls that are related to this part, and your models that are relevant and include the post request that you are using (if you were using post).

Comment: Jimmar, I did add my Serializers, Urls and Models. Also i'm using Postam and doing simple POST request: http://127.0.0.1:8000/poll/Weather/

Comment: Your `Question` model as a poll_id `foreign_key` that is required, so when creating a new question you need to either provide a poll_id with it or you'd need to make the poll_id `null=True`

Comment: Jimmar, i was trying that. I did add null=True  everywhere i can, but still getting same error.

Comment: did you run `makemigrations` and `migrate` after making those changes to the model ?

Comment: yes, many times. I did delete DB as well. Same error.

Comment: does it work if you try to add it using the django admin interface ?

Answer (score 1):

I've cloned your repo and made those changes
in models.py

```py
class Question(models.Model):
    # ... keep as is, just changed the poll
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Polls, related_name='question', on_delete=DO_NOTHING, null=True, blank=True) #blank=True is there so you can make it work on the admin interface
```

and in views.py

```py
class Questions(APIView):
    # .. everything before this is as is
    def post(self, request, format=None, **kwargs):
        title = kwargs['topic'] # extract the title from the url
        serializer = QuestionSerializer(data={**request.data, 'title':title}) # create a new serializer with the data you have + adding the title
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

and this would work, however this is not the proper way to get this done.
The endpoints shouldn't be used that way, REST endpoints are usually like this

```
# this end point would list all the questions if called with `get` and would be used to create a new question if called with `post`
path('question/', Questions.as_view(), name="question"),

# this end point would display the question with the provided topic if called with `get` and would be used to update it called with `patch` or `put`
path('question/<str:topic>/', QuestionDetail.as_view(), name="questionDetail"),
```

It doesn't make sense in your case to have an end point that lists all questions, but you should use that url for creating questions or you can have the `/poll/` endpoint take care of creating a poll with all the questions and answers from one request.

To make things easier, you can use the [generic APIViews provided by DRF](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/)

take a look at those specifically:

- [ListCreateAPIView](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listcreateapiview)
- [RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#retrieveupdatedestroyapiview)

and this is from the official tutorial showing and example of how to use it
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views/#using-generic-class-based-views

I highly recommend going through all of the oficial tutorials

Comment: I will test it later today and will come back to you with results. Thank you!